# Find a basis for the subspace of polynomials of degree 3

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbb{P}_{3}$ be the collection of all polynomials of degree
at most 3. Find a basis for the subspace consisting of those polynomials
$p$ such that $p(1)=0$.

Comment: What are your own thoughts on this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Those are exactly the polynomials having an $x-1$ factor.

So, a basis will be $(x-1)\cdot 1,\ \ (x-1)\cdot x,\ \ (x-1)\cdot x^2$. (Verify it!)